# Contesting Duplicates and other Moderation Errors

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Quite often I read questions that are closed as Duplicate or as not constructive and think: "it's not a duplicate or it is constructive, and I have just the answer he/she is looking for".

I wonder if a useful feature addition to Stack Overflow and the wider StackExchange series would be to have a button or some kind of thumbs up/thumbs down and comments area on the post notice. That way if a moderation action gets significant negative feedback, they may considerer and revert their actions.

For example just today I was reading a question regarding [clicking the map on OSMDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421159/why-mapview-ontouchlistener-is-only-fired-once), and was able to overcome the OP's problem. I wanted to post but it was marked as duplicate against another question that was regarding Google Android maps, so different.

It would be nice to have a quick and simple way of marking the moderation action as a possible error with a comment so they may review. I appreciate the mods are very busy and may not have the time to read all questions fully, this may help all of us out. Mods could then say review the top 10 or 20 most contested actions on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have this, it's just not single-click accessible. Simply click the 'flag' link, select 'other' and enter something similar to this:

> I don't feel this is a duplicate because [kittens]. Could a moderator review this closing?

And if the post was closed *by* a moderator:

> I don't feel this is a duplicate because [monkeys], can another moderator please sanity check this closing and perhaps revert it?

Moderators honestly do not mind being asked to review a call made by another mod, mistakes do sometimes happen. Additionally, moderators really don't mind having a call they made reviewed by one of their colleagues - that kind of feedback is critical for honing a decision making process that scales to a very large volume.

Additionally, you can [@mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) one of the closers or moderators in a comment.

As for making that one click accessible - not sure that's really needed as it really is just a couple of extra clicks.

Comment: yet another option is to edit (suggest-edit) the question to make it crystal clear for readers that it's different from a dupe / constructive. This will automagically push it into [reopen queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen), where users reading it could vote reopen (that is, if the text of revised question makes a compelling evidence in favor of reopen)

Comment: Thanks perfect. I always thought that was for forum abuse so never investigated it.

Comment: Not to mention that as a Moderator I don't mind revisiting decisions I've made and changing them if the circumstances warrant.  We're pretty open to gut-checks, and that's a good thing.

Comment: It's _primarily_ for reporting problematic content or behavior, but there are always exceptions - so we have the generic catch all to handle that. As @gnat points out (which I would have if I weren't out of coffee) - try to fix whatever might be wrong with a post prior to flagging, it will stand a _much_ better chance of being reopened.